# How to calculate number of processor cores in PHP script (linux)?

Tags: php, linux, pthreads

I'm trying to use pthreads for multithreading. I'm creating pool with constructor. First parameter is number of Workers.

```
$pool = new Pool(8, 'WebWorker');
```

I want to detect count of processor cores automatically. Something like this:

```
$pool = new Pool(get_processor_cores_number(), 'WebWorker');
```

How is it possible with PHP?

Answer (score 15):

If the server is a Linux machine you can do it with the following snippet:

```
$ncpu = 1;

if(is_file('/proc/cpuinfo')) {
    $cpuinfo = file_get_contents('/proc/cpuinfo');
    preg_match_all('/^processor/m', $cpuinfo, $matches);
    $ncpu = count($matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: this should be faster: `$ncpu = substr_count((string)@file_get_contents('/proc/cpuinfo'),"\nprocessor")+1;` - first off substr_count is faster than preg_match_all, and we only do a single open() instead of 2, and if the file is unreadable, substr_count returns 0 and the +1 turns 0 into 1, but when the file is readable, substr_count will skip the first processor because it does not start with a newline, and the +1 accounts for that too :)

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of ways, you can even open `/sys/devices/system/cpu/online` and read the *online* CPUs :)

Comment: Both options are awesome, anything to avoid `shell_exec` :)

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like that, of course your server should be in linux:

```
function get_processor_cores_number() {
    $command = "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l";

    return  (int) shell_exec($command);
}
```

You will execute a shell command then cast it to int.

Comment: PHP doesnt have any build-in capability for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know any native php function able to achieve that.

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l` is utter ugly.

you can do the same with a single process instead of three and two pipes:

`grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @teknoraver and you can do it with 0 pipes and 0 extra processes: ```substr_count(file_get_contents("/proc/cpuinfo"),"processor");```

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone looking for a easy function to get total CPU cores for **Windows** and **Linux** both OS.

```php
function get_processor_cores_number() {
    if (PHP_OS_FAMILY == 'Windows') {
        $cores = shell_exec('echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%');
    } else {
        $cores = shell_exec('nproc');
    }

    return (int) $cores;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension exposing sysconf: [krakjoe/sysconf](https://github.com/krakjoe/sysconf)

```
<?php
$cpusConfigured = sysconf(SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
$cpusOnline     = sysconf(SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
?>
```

Most applications only care about the number configured.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid spinning up a whole new shell to get simple information out of the OS when you can.  This is extremely slow and is a memory hog as you're spawning an entire command interpreter for a single simple task.

Here is a quick function to do it on Linux or Windows that doesn't require spawning a whole new shell:

```
function get_total_cpu_cores() {
   return (int) ((PHP_OS_FAMILY == 'Windows')?(getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")+0):substr_count(file_get_contents("/proc/cpuinfo"),"processor"));
}
```

This will work on any semi-modern windows installation (since at LEAST Windows 95) and will work on most, if not all, flavors of Linux assuming you have the rights to read /proc/cpuinfo.  But most installations make that world readable... so shouldn't have any problems.

Further note to bear in mind technically this is showing you the CPU cores available as the OS sees it.  Both Windows and Linux see hyperthreaded CPU threads as cores even though they aren't physical cores.  That said, this should still work for what you're trying to do unless you REALLY need to know the number of physical cores on a machine.  Then you're in for a more involved process.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In my own library, I have a function for this among other things. You can easily modify it where it uses nonstandard PHP functions.

For instance, I cache the result so you can ignore that. Then I have functions to check if we are running on Linux, Mac or Windows. You could insert a similar check of your own there. For executing the actual system specific check I use my own `Process` class which allows things such as reconnecting to running processes on subsequent requests to check status, output etc. But you can change that and just use `exec`.

```
public static function getNumberOfLogicalCPUCores() {
    $numCores = CacheManager::getInstance()->fetch('System_NumberOfLogicalCPUCores');
    if(!$numCores) {
        if(System::isLinux() || System::isMac()) {
            $getNumCoresProcess = new Process("grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo");
            $getNumCoresProcess->executeAndWait();
            $numCores = (int)$getNumCoresProcess->getStdOut();
        }
        else if(System::isWindows()) {
            // Extract system information
            $getNumCoresProcess = new Process("wmic computersystem get NumberOfLogicalProcessors");
            $getNumCoresProcess->executeAndWait();
            $output = $getNumCoresProcess->getStdOut();
            // Lazy way to avoid doing a regular expression since there is only one integer in the output on line 2. 
            // Since line 1 is only text "NumberOfLogicalProcessors" that will equal 0.
            // Thus, 0 + CORE_COUNT, which equals CORE_COUNT, will be retrieved.
            $numCores = array_sum($getNumCoresProcess->getStdOutAsArray());
        }
        else {
            // Assume one core if this is some unkown OS
            $numCores = 1;
        }
        CacheManager::getInstance()->store('System_NumberOfLogicalCPUCores', $numCores);
    }

    return $numCores;
}
```

Comment: for linux, `return (int)(rtrim(shell_exec('nproc')));` should suffice

Comment: @hanshenrik: Is that a standard command I can trust to be available in all flavors?

Comment: yes, pretty much all linux systems has this, because it's a part of GNU Coreutils, and all mainstream linux distros i can think of ship with GNU Coreutils (probably not Slitaz Linux Floppy, but that's like the only exception i can think of..)

Comment: nproc, being part of coreutils, is more likely to be available than grep, because grep is not part of coreutils.

Comment: @hanshenrik: Thanx, great. I'll update my library to use this approach instead then.

Comment: btw nrpoc prints the number of cores and then prints an `\n` (newline character) - i used rtrim() here to remove the newline character, but cast-to-int will ignore the newline char anyway, so if you're into micro-optimization memes, throwing out the rtrim() should make it faster without changing functionality.