# How to get the processor core number on which the script is running on a linux system with PHP (similar to sched_getcpu() in C)

Tags: php, c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

I would like to know which processor core my php process is running on. It seems possible to do this in C like so:

```c
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("The CPU Number is: %d", sched_getcpu());
}
```

Does anyone know of an existing wrapper for PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of processor cores in PHP script (linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970270/how-to-calculate-number-of-processor-cores-in-php-script-linux)

Comment: @Syscall Not really since that question is about getting the total amount of processor cores whereas I would like to know the specific core the processor is running on

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Apart from the obvious answer that you can compile the `C` example and use it in PHP either as an external call, or as a library trough `FFI`, there is a simpler way by using the `ps` shell utility. The `psr` column of the `ps` report will tell you on which cpu the process is running. Combined it with the `-p` to get the cpu for a specific `pid`, use `getmypid()` to find your pid.

When you put all together as a function `getmycpu()` it will looks like this:

```
<?php
function getmycpu() {
    $mypid = getmypid();
    $cpucore = (int)shell_exec("ps -o psr= -p $mypid");
    return $cpucore;
}
?>
```

Now you can use the function to get the core on which the process is running

```
<?php
$output = getmycpu();
echo "You are running on cpu #$output", PHP_EOL;
?>
```